# One of my functions on the TicTacToe game in C++

Tags: c++, tic-tac-toe

I have a little problem with the function " JOUER ".
It's been a few days I'm working on it, but I can't see the problemS. 
The main issue is:  [Error] expected primary-expression before 'int' and [Error] expected primary-expression before 'char'. 
Here is the code:

---

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
enum etat { victoire, continuer, null };
int qntMouv = 0;
class TicTacToe {
public:
TicTacToe();
etat etatJeux ();
void affichTab() const ;      
bool getXOMouv (char symbolMouv);
bool mouvValid (int x, int y) const;
void recommence ();
void game(); 
void jouer();
private:
char tableau[3][3];         
}; // fin classe TicTacToe

TicTacToe::TicTacToe() 
{   
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
tableau[i][j] = ' ';     
qntMouv = 0;   // le tableau  est vide          
} // fin constructeur TicTacToe


bool TicTacToe::mouvValid (int x, int y) const{

    int lig, col;

    if  ( lig >= 0 && lig <= 2  && col >=0 && col <= 2 &&  tableau[x] [y] == ' ' )
        return true;

    else return false;

} // fin du bool mouvValid


   etat TicTacToe::etatJeux () {

if  ((tableau[0][0]) && (tableau[1][0]) && (tableau[2][0]))  return victoire; //colomne

else if ((tableau[0][1]) && (tableau[1][1]) && (tableau[2][1])) return victoire; //colomne

        else if ((tableau[0][2]) && (tableau[1][2]) && (tableau[2][2])) return victoire;  // colomne

            else if((tableau[0][0] ) && (tableau[0][1] ) && (tableau[0][2]))return victoire;  // lignme 

                else if ((tableau[1][0]) && (tableau[1][1]) && (tableau[1][2])) return victoire;  // ligne

                        else if ((tableau[2][0]) && (tableau[2][1]) && (tableau[2][2])) return victoire;  // ligne

                                else if ((tableau[0][0]) && (tableau[1][1]) && (tableau[2][2])) return victoire; // diago

                                        else if ((tableau[0][2]) && (tableau[1][1]) && (tableau[2][0])) return victoire; // // diago

                                            else if (qntMouv < 9) return continuer;

                                                 return null;

} // fin  etatJeux

void TicTacToe::recommence () {

qntMouv = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)

for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++)

tableau[i][j] = ' '; 

}  // fin recommence
```

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: [Error] cannot call member function 'void TicTacToe::affichTab() const' without object

Comment: The error just means what it says. Here `TicTacToe::affichTab();` you are trying to call the function without an object. Either make the method static or call it on an object

Comment: There is a lot of formatting issues there, brackets don't add up, the `TicTacToe::affichTab();` is the least problem

Answer (score -1):

There are a few issues in your code. This looks like it's one of your first adventures with C++. Maybe you should read some [tutorials](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/) on the topic. Besides, when you try to write some piece of code try writing it part by part, check if it compiles/works as expected then move forward.
To give you some directions I'll try to list some noticeable problems in your code:

- Missing brackets (mostly `}`)
- Cannot call a non-static class member without an object `TicTacToe::affichTab() const` - probably you just wanted to call `affichTab()`
- `jouer` function should probably be a membet method of the `TicTacToe` class since it calls a lot of its members
- Methods called from `jouer()` don't match their definition, for example:

  - `getXOMouv()` called vs `getXOMouv (char symbolMouv)` declared
  - `mouvValid()` called vs `mouvValid (int x, int y)` declared - I can guess you wanted to call this with `x` and `y` arguments
- The expression `if (joueur == 1) ? 'X' : 'O';` is incorrect, you would want to use if or ternary operator and assing the result to some variable probably, for example:

  `const char var = (joueur == 1) ? 'X' : 'O';`
- The `if (etatJeux==victoire)` should be a member call, so you're missing the brackets (`etatJeux()`)
- Inside the `jouer` method you have a `return 0` statement which is incorrect considering the method is declared with void return type
- Inside the same method `int tableau[x][y];` is unused. Considering the method should be a class member the variable hides the class member of the same name

Comment: i'm working on all this issues. i'll share the code when it's done and working properly

Comment: What does it mean "not yet working"? Still doesn't compile? What's the error?

Comment: Have you updated the definition to 'void TicTacToe::jouer ()?'

Comment: yes. i guess it's almost  there. it's not compiling yet because:  [Error]  expected primary-expression before 'int'  and [Error] expected primary-expression before 'char'

Comment: if you copy/paste the updated code, the lines are: 41, 42, 46, 50

Comment: Your method calls are incorrect: getXOMouv(char symbolMouv); mouvValid(int x, int y);. just omit the argument types and it should be fixed. I believe you should read some more about the basics to more understand the topic. For example: [basic syntax](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_basic_syntax.htm) or [function calls](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/functions/)

Comment: Also, I can see that what you called 'var' should actually be named 'symbolMouv' variable

Comment: You're the best. Yes, now  it's compiling. \o/... but not working yet...

Comment: i'm a beginner. This is my third code. I don't hide I'm a little lost with those new concepts.

Comment: Since the compilation problem is fixed you could probably close the question